# Is it possible to registry class , unity container ,c#

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'd like to use [unity container](http://unitycontainer.org/articles/introduction.html)  to implement a singleton design.

for example:

create the singleton:

```
container.RegistryInstance<IClass>(new Class())
```

get the singleton instance:

```
container.Resolve<IClass>()
```

**Can I do the same but with a class and not with interface?**

for example:

create the singleton:

```
container.RegistryInstance<Class>(new Class())
```

get the singleton:

```
container.Resolve<Class>()
```

Comment: Yes, you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. In that case, you do not need to provide a type argument to `RegistryInstance`.

From http://unitycontainer.org/tutorials/registration/instance.html:

> The simplest instance registration does not require any additional parameters other than instance itself:
>
> ```
> var instance = new Service();
>
> container.RegisterInstance(instance);
> ```
>
> Resolving type Service like this `container.Resolve<Service>()` will return an instance of the Service object we registered.